# The minimal free resolution of a module with a direct summand is not periodic

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Assume that $R$ is a local ring and that $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module with a free direct summand, then why its minimal free resolution cannot be periodic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M$ has a periodic free resolution of period $d\ge 1$, then $M$ is isomorphic to its $d$th syzygy. Now apply Lemma 0.1(ii) in Eisenbud's paper [*Homological algebra on a complete intersection, with an application to group representations*](http://www.msri.org/~de/papers/pdfs/1980-002.pdf) which says that the kernels of the minimal free resolution starting from some rank (depending on $\operatorname{depth} R$) have no free direct summands.